# Critique request: Logo design for a tech company

Tags: logo, critique

I am creating a logo for a tech company, **Reitech**. The company creates software, tools, and plugins. The company is also doing programming consulting.

I am not a designer, but I like working with design and improve my skills, so I would love some feedback on the first draft I made. I created a wordmark/logotype design, and an abstract logo (at least that is what I think the terms are called).

### Background

I tried to incorporate the symbols, `<`,`>` as the underlying theme. I got inspired to combine these symbols creating the, `ᚱ`, from the Futhark runic alphabet as the capital letter. (I thought about using `</>` as a theme as well, but weren't able to incorporate the `/`).

[image: Logo design]

#### I have a few questions:

1. Is the logo readable? Does it read "Reitech"? Maybe the "e"s in the logo are difficult to recognize?
2. Does the spacing (kerning) between the letters need some adjustment?
3. Did I go overboard on trying to force the theme? Maybe a subtle change is better, like only using `<` in the "c"?
4. Is the logo (inside the capsule) too similar to the Bluetooth logo?

Any other type of feedback is welcome.

Comment: I disagree that it’s particularly hard to read. I saw the logo before reading the text, and my immediate thought was, “Reitech? The hell is that?” – or rather, that was my second thought. My _first_ thought was, “Ooh, botched Bluetooth logo!”, so a definite yes to #4.

Comment: But as a technical item it could be good for a blacksmith who makes iron and copper stuff based on 1000...1300 years old Scandinavian models.

Comment: I also disagree that it's hard to read. But it seems strange to me to see Futhark inspired letters in *lowercase*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unreadable in my opinion.... well.... it *can* be read, but requires *way* too much effort from the viewer to figure it out. It's simply *too* stylized if the goal is easy readability.

At *no point* would I ever, in a million years, know the intention was to represent brackets (`<`, `>`). Especially since seemingly the *only* right bracket is in the R. I can't count those horrible `e`s.... `:)` To me, it just looks like horribly hard to read type.

The R alone, honestly... merely feels like a bluetooth rip off (which it kind of is from your explanation).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I kind of thought it would be too difficult to read. Maybe it's better to get back to the drawing board, and consider using a font instead.

Comment: @John I'm all for *not* relying on a font. In fact, I *really* prefer logos that *don't* simply use a font they found (so their third cousin, twice removed, can recreate the logo merely by buying/downloading the font). But you should still keep readability/legibility in mind. -- of course... there's no law which states a logo must be readable `:)` The Death Metal genre of music is infamous for impossible to read logos. `;)`

Comment: Agreed on all points with Scott here.

Answer (score 1):

Too close to the Bluetooth symbol and almost unreadable. Honestly if you just type the name in Arial Black it can already look better than this. I think you need to reconsider the design.